# BPF: sock_ops equivalent for UDP sockets

Tags: networking, ebpf, bpf, systems-programming

BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCK_OPS is a BPF program type which is called [when a set of actions is performed on a TCP socket.](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/bpf.h#L6606)

Right now, I am using it to mark TCP sockets that are trying to connect with an fwmark.

I want to do the same for UDP sockets, but unfortunately the BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCK_OPS probe is not called on UDP packets.

Is there an equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP sockets don't really connect, so similar event to trigger on. Closest thing would be to trigger on socket creation with the use of a [BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SOCK](https://ebpf-docs.dylanreimerink.nl/linux/program-type/BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SOCK/) program.

You can also find a [list of all BPF sockets here](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/libbpf/program_types.html#program-types-and-elf). Since you want to set a socket option, you can also [look at the man page of the bpf helpers](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html). For `bpf_setsockopt`, you will find a list of attach points for which this helper will be available. Note though that for some BPF probes, you can also edit the socket mark directly (e.g. `BPF_CGROUP_INET_SOCK_CREATE`) without calling the helper function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I ended up using `BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SOCK` like you suggested. I was surprised that it's possible to edit the socket mark directly in the struct, without calling the BPF helper for that.